# What is the best way of loading huge size files from local to hdfs

Tags: hadoop

I have dir which contain multiple folder with N number of files in each dir. single file size would be 15 GB. I don't know what is the best way to copy/move the file from local to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this (using traditional methods), like,

1. `hdfs dfs -put /path/to/localdir/ hdfs://path/to/hdfsdir`
2. `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /path/to/localdir/ hdfs://path/to/hdfsdir`
3. `hdfs dfs -moveFromLocal /path/to/localdir/ hdfs://path/to/hdfsdir`
4. `hadoop distcp file:///path/to/localdir/ hdfs://namenode:port/path/to/hdfsdir`

Option 1 & 2 are same in your case. There will not be any difference in copy time.

Option 3 might take some more time as it copies the data to HDFS filesystem (same as `-put`) and then deletes the file from the local filesystem.

Option 4 is a tricky one. It is designed for large inter/intra-cluster copying. But you can use the same command for local files also by providing local file URL with "file://" prefix. It is not the optimal solution w.r.t distcp as the tool is designed to work in parallel (using MapReduce) and as the file is on local, it cannot make use of its strength. (You can try by creating a mount on the cluster nodes which might increase the performance of distcp)